# deleting records that has recursive relationships in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have below relationship in my model. UserStatement has levelupStatement and parentStatement which has a-to one relationship between. The problem I have is when I try to delete levelupStatement. I have nullify both end of the relationship and when I try to delete like below: (mainuserstatement is the parentStatement)

```
self.mainUserStatementModel.levelupStatement = nil;
self.mainUserStatementModel.levelupTerm = nil;
[[ASHCoreDataStack defaultStack].managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.mainUserStatementModel.levelupStatement];

The error I am getting is: 
      Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument'.
```

I know that my managedObjectContext exists. So problem should not be there. How can I safely delete the levelupStatement without effecting levelupterm and parentStatement?

[image: core data model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the order of those lines of code:

```
[[ASHCoreDataStack defaultStack].managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.mainUserStatementModel.levelupStatement];
self.mainUserStatementModel.levelupStatement = nil;
self.mainUserStatementModel.levelupTerm = nil;
```

In fact, if your `parentStatement` relationship is set to 'Nullify' then you do not need the second of these lines: CoreData will automatically nil out the `levelUpStatement`.  Check the relationship in the Data Model Inspector:

[image]